# How to style function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function makeMove(row, col) {
    if (!isGameStarted) return;

    const cell = document.querySelector(`.row:nth-child(${row + 1}) .cell:nth-child(${col + 1})`);
    if (cell.textContent !== "") return;

    if (currentPlayer === 1) {
        cell.textContent = "X";
        gameBoard[row][col] = "X";
    } else if (currentPlayer === 2) {
        cell.textContent = "O";
        gameBoard[row][col] = "O";
    }

    if (checkWin()) {
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById("message");
        resultDiv.textContent = "You won, " + getCurrentPlayerName() + "!";
        isGameStarted = false;
    } else if (checkDraw()) {
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById("message");
        resultDiv.textContent = "It's a draw!";
        isGameStarted = false;
    } else {
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 1 ? 2 : 1;
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById("current-player");
        resultDiv.textContent = "It's your turn " + getCurrentPlayerName();
    }
}
```

I have this part of my code. My question is how can I style `getCurrentPlayerName()`? "It's your turn" needs to be by default, but I need to highlight player name. For example, different color and different font size. In my html I just have divs `#message` and `#current-player`, I did everything in Javascript.

Comment: use `innerHTML` and then use html

Comment: Use a span: `"You won, <span class='playername'>" + name + "</span>!"`. And since you're using a span you can't simply insert it using `.textContent`;

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have the style for each player change you can set the inner HTML of the resultDiv to have a span containing the player name and that span can be styled depending on the player.

You can use this below example to get familiar with setting innerHTML. You can make it a lot more condensed but I have used more lines to keep it clear

The JS:

- Sets the innerHTML compared to your textContent. This allows a span to be inserted which can be styled depending on the player

```
let currentPlayer = 1;

function displayMessage() {
    changeMessage();
}

function changeMessage() {
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 1 ? 2 : 1;
    const resultDiv = document.getElementById("current-player");
    resultDiv.innerHTML = getCurrentPlayerMessage()
}

function getCurrentPlayerMessage(){
    const teamColor = currentPlayer === 1 ? "red" : "blue";
    const playerName = getCurrentPlayerName();

    const playerSpan = `<span class="${teamColor}-player">${playerName}</span>`
    const messageHTML = "It's your turn " + playerSpan

    return messageHTML
}

function getCurrentPlayerName() {
    return currentPlayer === 1 ? "James" : "Giant";
}
```

The HTML:

- Just has a button to swap the player over and a message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="play.css" />
        <title>Header</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p id="current-player">No message set</p>        
       <button onclick="displayMessage()">Change player</button>
    </body>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>

</html>
```

The CSS:

- each player gets their own styling set here. this relates to the ${teamColor}-player class in the JS file

```
.blue-player{
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.red-player{
    color: red;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To style a JavaScript function, you typically do not directly style the function itself. Instead, you style the HTML elements that the function interacts with. In your case, the function seems to be part of a tic-tac-toe game and modifies the game board and displays messages.

Add CSS styles for the game board cells (X and O marks):

```
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*Style the result and current player elements:*/

#message, #current-player {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

<div id="game-board">
  <!-- Your game board cells go here -->
</div>
#game-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Is this answer generated by AI? Please refer to [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)